# Deepcopy of managed-proxy to a native-object (with delegate passed during construction)

Tags: c#, delegates, pinvoke

I have a native API with tree important functions, `CreateObject`, `DestroyObject` and `CloneObject`, and where `CreateObject` is expecting for a function pointer which I binded to some `NativeDelegate` in the managed code:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer]
public delegate double NativeDelegate(double);

internal static class NativeInterop
{
    [DllImport("native.dll", EntryPoint="CreateObject")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateObject(NativeDelegate fctn);

    [DllImport("native.dll", EntryPoint="DestroyObject")]
    public static extern void DestroyObject(IntPtr pa);

    [DllImport("native.dll", EntryPoint="CloneObject")]
    public static extern IntPtr CloneObject(IntPtr pa);
}
```

I've then created a proxy in managed code for object living in native world like this:

```
public class NativeObject : IDisposable
{
    public NativeObject(NativeDelegate fctn)
    {
        pa = NativeInterop.CreateObject(fctn);
        keepAlive = fctn; // Because delegate may no longer be referenced anywhere else in managed code.
    }
    public Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (pa == IntPtr.Zero) { return; }
        NativeInterop.DestroyObject(pa);
        pa = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    ~NativeObject()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private NativeDelegate keepAlive;
    private IntPtr pa;
}
```

NB: For tests I made so far, this is all fine. *The only trick for me was to keep constructor's delegate alive because it may no longer be referenced in managed code* while still being used by other native API calls through the proxy *(not reported in the sample code)*.

Now I'm wondering how I should clone this proxy. Currently i'm thinking of just:

```
public NativeObject Clone()
{
    if (pa == IntPtr.Zero) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Already disposed"); }

    var _pa = NativeInterop.CloneObject(pa); // Ask native API to make deep-copy on its side
    var _keepAlive = keepAlive; // Make shallow copy only for the delegate

    return new NativeObject(_pa, _keepAlive);
}
private NativeObject(IntPtr pa, NativeDelegate keepAlive)
{
    this.pa = pa;
    this.keepAlive = keepAlive; 
}
```

Because I have read [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/chapter2/events.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx) that delegates are immutable.

I'm somehow confident this is ok ... but somehow I'm walking on eggshells too ... can you confirm me cloning proxy in this way is ok and that I will not fall into race situations I've haven't figured out yet ? Will it be ok to make surface copy of the delegate **even with lambdas, lambda referring to local scope variables?**.

For instance:

```
var toto = new NativeObject((d) => 3.0*d);
var copy = toto.Clone();

toto = null;
GC.Collect();
copy.SomeOperation();
```

Comment: The `NativeDelegate` shouldn't be copied, i guess. You're cloning a `NativeObject`. and because this is a 'proxy' you'll pass the command to the native routines to copy itselfs. But the native object only uses the `NativeDelegate`, but isn't owner. So your implementation does make sense to me.. But i don't have any expirience passing delegates to native code.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Thanks. I'm trying to be very prudent here because in practice in the API I can create objects that contain sub-objects themselves tied to .NET delegate and finally clone the big object. _I have needed for other live-tracking lists for that ..._ anyway so far seems I have no crash (would have been really hard to trace).